# PiVPN Add Not Working

Tags: vpn

i am trying to set up vpn on my pi using pivpn.

i have successfully installed it and restarted my pi using the command as suggested in the official website: `curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash`
. (i ran the command with `sudo` to get it to work).

i now want to add a user, but it does not seem to work. it seems to be missing many files.

```
$-> pivpn add
cat: /etc/pivpn/INSTALL_USER: No such file or directory
Enter a Name for the Client:  client
/opt/pivpn/makeOVPN.sh: line 165: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/index.txt: No such file or directory
Enter the password for the client:  
Enter the password again to verify:  
spawn ./easyrsa build-client-full client
couldn't execute "./easyrsa": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn ./easyrsa build-client-full "client""
spawn openssl rsa -in pki/private/client.key -des3 -out pki/private/client.key
Can't open pki/private/client.key for reading, No such file or directory
1995638176:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:74:fopen('pki/private/client.key','r')
1995638176:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:81:
unable to load Private Key
expect: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"expect "Enter PEM pass phrase" { send "test\r" }"
/opt/pivpn/makeOVPN.sh: line 135: cd: pki: No such file or directory
```

has anyone else experienced this issue?

i have never set up VPN before so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of other people have experienced this recently, and there is [an open issue about it on the pivpn github](https://github.com/pivpn/pivpn/issues/521).

The most recent comments there suggest that the best way to proceed would be starting from a new freshly installed Raspbian image, if that is an option for you.